# Как реализовать таймер на Django для викторины в telegram боте?

Tags: django, telegram-bot

Здравствуйте уважаемые программисты!

Я делаю викторину в telegram боте на Django.
Суть заключается в том, что нужно выдавать вопрос с ответами пользователю на определенное время, а после окончание времени ему выдается следующий вопрос, но если пользователь вовремя ответил на вопрос, то таймер обновляется и ему выдаётся другой.

У меня в голове только мысль использовать Celery.
А именно, после выполнения функции отправки вопроса, создавать задачу, которая через определенное время снова выполнит эту функцию, а если пользователь уложился в этот промежуток времени и ответил, то остановить задачу и выполнять всё по новой.

Я не спец, но мне кажется, что создавать на каждый вопрос "таску" это не правильное решение.

Как подобное реализовать?

Прошу вас просветить меня.